# Accessible index page configured wrong (Jekyll + Github Pages)

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a Github site, ran it through some free SEO checkers for fun. Got an interesting issue I'm uncertain how to configure in this scenario, if it is even possible.

My website home page is accessible at both [`/`](http://arshoenclave.com/) and [`/index.html`](http://arshoenclave.com/index.html): it should only be accessible at `/`.

Anyone know how to make this configuration happen, or can anyone authoritatively say this either isn't an issue or cannot be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard convention that webservers send `/index.html` (or some variant like `/index.htm` or `/index.php` or whatever extension applies) when no filename is provided. So I might be wrong but I think it is not possible to prevent access through the 'real' url `/index.html` since `/` is only a kind of alias for it.